# Custom Incoming Call GUI in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I was trying to develop an application that show custom GUI on incoming call if that number exist in my database. It works ok. But some time it show up phone default Incoming GUI on my custom GUI..
It might be take some time while checking in database meanwhile it shows phone default GUI.
Is it possible to wait/hide/never show default GUI of incoming call ?.

One more problem is once my activity is in foreground and want start the my activity on incoming call and shot popup contain accept/reject GUI. because activity is in foreground it is not created second time it doesn't shown popup(accept/reject) GUI.

Comment: you have to improve 50% to 60% so anybody would like to give answer

Comment: Can you shareyour solution for the above problem. I have same issue.  I have few contacts in my app DB, if incoming call is for these numbers i want to have a diff UI

Comment: ok.but it is not always display your custom UI, it may display sometimes default one.

Answer (score 1):

Add intent-filter tag in manifest of your custom UI(activity)

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

in ur broadcast receiver check incoming number and if exist open your activity.
see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485482/how-to-identify-incoming-call-and-outgoing-call-in-android).