# how to identify incoming call and outgoing call in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

how to get the events of incoming call and outgoing call in android separately.
Actually i was trying to develop an application that open on incoming call if number is exist in database and it work OK. but if i call from the device(outgoing call) and if number is exist in database still it open my application.
i want to restrict to open my application on outgoing call.

my manifest contain i receive incoming call like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter >             
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />             
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

IncomingCallReceiver:

```
MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

MyPhoneStateListener:

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
      switch(state) {
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
              Log.d("DEBUG", "IDLE");
          break;
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
              Log.d("DEBUG", "OFFHOOK");                        
              Intent i = new Intent(context, MyMainActivity.class);
              i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              context.startActivity(i);
          break;
          case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
              Log.d("DEBUG", "RINGING");
          break;
    }
}
```

can anyone help me to differentiate outgoing call from incoming call so i'll handle this events.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi please provide u'r code to get outgoing call duration....thanq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to restrict to open my application on outgoing call.

on `case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:` check if the previous state was `CALL_STATE_RINGING` or `CALL_STATE_IDLE` (for example by settings a different flag in both cases).
In the latter case proceed with opening your application, else do nothing

Comment: wow! its working by putting flags in CALL_STATE_RINGING or CALL_STATE_IDLE and checking in CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK case.Thanks.....

Comment: finally its done.Both(Martin nad Vineet) of your comments are useful for me.

Comment: I dont understand what this means can you explain? Or post the code?

Answer (score 4):

add `<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />` in your receiver and process it in your `onReceive()` method.

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter >             
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />             
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: now it is possible to outgoing call but in <intent-filter> because both PHONE_STATE and NEW_OUTGOING_CALL action, broadcast receiver execute both times and first action time NEW_OUTGOING_CALL execute and it doesn't start app but second action (PHONE_STATE) it start my application. i have handle both actions in single receiver. My code is in second comment.

Comment: you should put check in your onReceive() method like this:if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL))

Comment: if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")){
        Log.i("bosch","IN OUTGOING CALL.........");
     }else{
      Log.i("bosch","IN INCOMING CALL.........");
      MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener(context);
      TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
      context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      telephony.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
     }

Comment: actually two times action will be performed on IncomingCallReceiver. on first time it execute if part(android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) but on second action it execute else part and call my application. Now like (android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) can we handle incoming call in if condition instead of else part.

Comment: finally its done.Both(Vineet and Martin) of your comments are useful for me.Tanks....

Comment: Im having same issue! can you post the solution?

Comment: use the above code in the manifest file while defining the receiver and in your receiver check for action different action defined above in the onReceive() method.