# What is the name of the Activity that is called when the phone is ringing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, phone-call

When the phone rings I get a screen that pops up automatically with two buttons and the caller info. Where is this screen coming from ? What Activity? I know it is called from the intent android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE. But what is the activity name and how can I get to it?
[image]

Comment: use broadcast sender to call the number and broadcase receiver for getting the incoming call. no need the activity name of above screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links that is useful to you to perform some action on incoming call.
1) [link](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/)
2) [link](http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/DetectCalls/)

```
<activity android:name=".AcceptReject" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and incoming broadcast receiver like:

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >             
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />                               
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver :

```
if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        Log.i("System out", "IN OUTGOING CALL......... :IF");
        MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(
                    context);
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephony.listen(phoneListener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }    else {         
            Log.i("System out", "IN INCOMING CALL.........:else:receiver");             


    }
```

and your `MyPhoneStateListener`

```
class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
private final Context context;
private boolean NOTOFFHOOK = false; 
public MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: // by default phone is in idle state
        Log.d("System out", "IDLE");
        NOTOFFHOOK = true;      
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:   // when user receive call this method called
        Log.d("System out", "OFFHOOK, it flag: " + NOTOFFHOOK);

        if (NOTOFFHOOK == false) {
            // do your work on receiving call.
        }
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:   // while ringing 
        Log.d("System out", "RINGING");
        // do your work while ringing.

        break;
    }
}
```

}

Hope useful to you.

Comment: Thanks! any way I can hide the above screen? I want to customize my own screen.

Comment: yes. called your custom design activity from broadcard receiver. your activity in manifest like. check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks alot! However, the first time the acceptreject goes up you see the default screen come up for a split second(I think it has to do with the stacK). Any way to get around it? Also what about the outgoing screen can that be customized?

Comment: i never tried but, i think it is possible. Also android 2.3.x and after version you can not receiver call using your custom button,coz they restricted after that.

Comment: your custom incoming screen and default(phone) both are trying to display on screen, so it not sure that always your screen is top of the default one. '<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />' is for hide default screen.

Comment: Thanks! how can I do this with outgoing call? I see you have done this in the past....Hope I can return the favor one day!

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485482/how-to-identify-incoming-call-and-outgoing-call-in-android/7485794#7485794

Comment: I did . However I dont understand how you did this. The code that is written there is not updated. Can you please post the updated one. Thanks!