# how to check if microphone is turned on or off

Tags: android

all I am working on an app,where I just want to check if microphone is on or off.
i.e when the microphone is recording audio,it should show on.when it is not it should show off.
[How to check whether microphone is used by any background app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633513/how-to-check-whether-microphone-is-used-by-any-background-app)
I tried this and also saw about AudioRecorder in android developer site.But I am not getting it right.Can anyone help me??Thanks in advance .

Edit:
can anyone suggest how to run it in background

Comment: See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633513/how-to-check-whether-microphone-is-used-by-any-background-app]........ might help you..!!

Comment: can anyone suggest how to run it as a background service