# How do I go about implementing a monitoring app

Tags: java, android, lua, monitoring, coronasdk

I am trying to build a monitoring app using LUA in corona labs. I was wondering how I would go about doing that.

Background: the app should notify the user when there is another app or outside third party accessing the camera/microphone.

I'm thinking trying to get access to the devices resource manager and it notify the app when the camera and microphone is being used.
I haven't come across anything like this before. Am I on the right path? Or am I way off? How would you go about doing this?

I'm not expecting a definite answer, just a nudge in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this kind of behavior is not what Corona is designed for.  You would likely have to use native tools, or Corona native if you want to use corona for your UI, to access this kind of data.

There is an interesting discussion about how it can be done in Android here [How to check whether microphone is used by any background app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633513/how-to-check-whether-microphone-is-used-by-any-background-app), hope it helps!