# Check Microphone is in use or not by other app?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I am facing an error while I start my audio/screen recorder and open my audio recorder app and start the service for recording audio the app crashes.
 I don't know why I am facing this problem.

Error trace from logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.babluboro.urecorder, PID: 10632
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.babluboro.urecorder.RecordingService@dee6d7d with Intent { cmp=com.example.babluboro.urecorder/.RecordingService }: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:229)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1924)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:943)
            at com.example.babluboro.urecorder.RecordingService.startRecording(RecordingService.java:126)
            at com.example.babluboro.urecorder.RecordingService.onStartCommand(RecordingService.java:97)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4128)
```

**Recording Service.java**

```
public class RecordingService extends Service {

    private String mFileName = null;
    private String mFilePath = null;

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "RecordingService";

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private DBHelper mDatabase;

    private long mStartingTimeMillis = 0;
    private long mElapsedMillis = 0;

    private static final String PREF_RECORDING_KEY = "prefs_recording_channel";
    private String channelType;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mDatabase = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        channelType = sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_RECORDING_KEY, "0");
    }

    class MyServiceBinder extends Binder{

        public RecordingService getService(){
            return RecordingService.this;
        }
    }

    private IBinder mBinder = new MyServiceBinder();

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, RecordingActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("URecorder")
                .setContentText("recording...")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.microphone_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);
        startRecording();

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    public void startRecording() {
        setFileNameAndPath();
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFilePath);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

        if(channelType == "Mono") {
            mRecorder.setAudioChannels(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO);
        }

        if(channelType == "Stereo"){
            mRecorder.setAudioChannels(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO);
        }

        if (MySharedPreferences.getPrefHighQuality(this)) {
            mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
        }

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
            mRecorder.start();
            mStartingTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setFileNameAndPath(){

        int count = 0;
        File f;

        do{
            count++;

            mFileName = "URecorder " + (mDatabase.getCount() + count)  + ".m4a";
            mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            mFilePath += "/URecorder/" + mFileName;

            f = new File(mFilePath);

        }while (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mRecorder != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            File file = new File(mFilePath);
            file.delete();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }


    public void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mElapsedMillis = (System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartingTimeMillis);
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Recording Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            mDatabase.addRecording(mFileName, mFilePath, mElapsedMillis);

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "exception", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**RecordingActivity**

```
    toolbar_main = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar_main);

        folderBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.folder_button);

        waveHeader = (MultiWaveHeader) findViewById(R.id.waveHeader);
        circleSpinner = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circleSpinner);
        pulsator = (PulsatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.pulsator);
        recordBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);
        chronometer_id = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer_id);

        folderBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(RecordingActivity.this, AllRecordsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                chronometer_id.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            }
        });

        recordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onRecord(uStartRecording);
                uStartRecording = !uStartRecording;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings_popup, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:

                Intent intent = new Intent(RecordingActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    private void onRecord(boolean start) {

        serviceIntent = new Intent(this, RecordingService.class);
        recordBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.save_icon);

        if (start) {

            bindService();
            folderBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pulsator.setCount(2);
            pulsator.start();

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/URecorder");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            startService(serviceIntent);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
            rotation.setFillAfter(true);
            circleSpinner.startAnimation(rotation);

            chronometer_id.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer_id.start();

        } else {
            folderBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recordingService.stopRecording();
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            isServiceBound = false;
            stopService(serviceIntent);
            recordBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.microphone_icon);
            timeWhenPaused = chronometer_id.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            circleSpinner.clearAnimation();
            pulsator.stop();
            chronometer_id.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            getPermissionToRecordAudio();
        }
    }

    public void getPermissionToRecordAudio() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Record, Read & Write External Storage permissions are required to do the task.");
                builder.setTitle("Please grant those permissions");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                                RecordingActivity.this,
                                new String[]{
                                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                },
                                RECORD_AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE
                        );
                    }
                });
                builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel",null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }else{

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    RECORD_AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == RECORD_AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length == 3 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this,"Permissions denied.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(isServiceBound != false) {
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            isServiceBound = false;
            stopService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }

    private void bindService(){

        if(serviceConnection == null){
            serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
                @Override
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
                    RecordingService.MyServiceBinder myServiceBinder=(RecordingService.MyServiceBinder)iBinder;
                    recordingService = myServiceBinder.getService();
                    isServiceBound = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
                    isServiceBound=false;
                }
            };
        }

        bindService(serviceIntent ,serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }
}
```

This is what happens when i try to start recording in my app.
Link to it is below.

[showing my app crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxGy8.gif)

Comment: post log trace of logcat so others could help you out

Comment: i have posted the logcat

Comment: can u post code from Recording service class

Comment: please post ur android manifest file showing permissions you  declared

Comment: posted the recording service and recording activity

Comment: did u fix it broo??

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have permission to use the microphone.
Try adding this to your manifest file.

This is the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Put it outside the application block like this:

```
...
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" /> 
</manifest>
```

Then you can use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35637498/1571605) to check if the mic is in use:

```
private boolean validateMicAvailability(){
    Boolean available = true;
    AudioRecord recorder =
            new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 44100,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT, 44100);
    try{
        if(recorder.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED ){
            available = false;

        }

        recorder.startRecording();
        if(recorder.getRecordingState() != AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING){
            recorder.stop();
            available = false;

        }
        recorder.stop();
    } finally{
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
    }

    return available;
}
```

Comment: its already added.. The problem is that when microphone is in use by other application my recorder crashes while recording.. I just want to toast a message to the user that "Microphone is in use by other application" but i dont know how to do that

Comment: I think I added what you need.

Comment: can i check that other application is using microphone from this code

Comment: Yes it should do that.